# PHP не читает код с <??>

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache

Так. столкнулся с проблемой. php не читает мой код в таких скобках - `<? ?>` зато в `<?php ?>` читает запросто. дело в том что у меня весь код написан как-раз таки в таких скобках.

вопрос - как в конфигурации php добавить чтение такого вида кода.

`short_open_tag` у меня стоит на On.

Comment: `short_open_tag у меня стоит на On` внимательно перепроверьте. Может быть не тот php.ini смотрите? `phpinfo()` в помощь

Comment: всегда существует ненулевая вероятность, что что то пошло не так (не тот конфиг, написали, но не сохранили), поэтому, лучше открыть phpinfo() и подсмотреть

Comment: понял спасибо большое

Comment: вы оказались правы. у меня оно стояло на off.

Comment: `echo ini_get("short_open_tag");` для проверки и `phpinfo();` для выяснения какие ini файлы подрубаются

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить в php.init `short_open_tag = 1` или `short_open_tag = On`.

В документации написано, что значение по умолчанию On, но, например, в моей конфигурации он был Off.

Обратите внимание, что файлов с конфигурацией может быть несколько и одни предназначены для работы веб-интерфейса (/etc/php//apache2/php.ini), другие для работы с консолью (/etc/php//cli/php.ini).

Особенности к разным версиям PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag